# How to center a ButtonGroup using Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to center a button group using Material UI in React, no matter what i do it floats to the left.

```
<Container>
    <ButtonGroup style={{alignItems:"center"}} color="primary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
        <Button onClick={()=>{setDonation(1)}}>$1</Button>
        <Button onClick={()=>{setDonation(5)}}>$5</Button>
        <Button onClick={()=>{setDonation(10)}}>$10</Button>
        <Button onClick={()=>{setDonation(25)}}>$25</Button>
    </ButtonGroup>
</Container>
```

Here is a picture of the chrome inspector:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that you can use Box component as a container with all the properties of a div container in css (At least the necesary ones)

```
<Box 
    display="flex" 
    flexDirection="column"
    alignItems="center"
    justifyContent="center"
>
    <ButtonGroup style={{textAlign:"center"}} color="primary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
        <Button onClick={()=>{setDonation(1)}}>$1</Button>
        <Button onClick={()=>{setDonation(5)}}>$5</Button>
        <Button onClick={()=>{setDonation(10)}}>$10</Button>
        <Button onClick={()=>{setDonation(25)}}>$25</Button>
    </ButtonGroup>
</Box>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can center the ButtonGroup by applying the following CSS attributes to the container.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});

const classes = useStyles();

<Container className={classes.container}>
    <ButtonGroup
      color="primary"
      aria-label="outlined primary button group"
    >
        <Button>$1</Button>
        <Button>$5</Button>
        <Button>$10</Button>
        <Button>$25</Button>
    </ButtonGroup>
</Container>
```

There is documentation here too https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/.